# 3D graph in Rstudio (time vs intensity vs coefficient)

Tags: graphics, 3d

I'm trying to replicate the following graph:

[image: graph]

I have a dataset with a timeseries of  intensity (4 different loads) and coefficient.

Does anyone know which R function is the best to produce graphs like that?

I've tried the plotly function but didn't get the desired result